# Update JSONB using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, jsonb

The following SQL statement, towards a multi-schema PostgreSQL (v.12) DB, is a perfectly valid one and it achieves the intended result.

I need to update a deep JSONB value as shown below:

```sql
UPDATE schema."Some_table_name" SET jsonb_col = jsonb_set(jsonb_col, '{path,to,key}', '"string value"') WHERE id = 1;
```

When I try to do the above from python using `psycopg2`, I don't get any errors, but no update either.

```py
def update_method(schema, path, value):
   q = f"""UPDATE {schema}."Some_table_name" SET jsonb_col = jsonb_set(jsonb_col, '{path}', '{value}') WHERE id = 1"""
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute(q)
   conn.commit()
   cur.close()

update_method('schema_name', '{path,to,key}', '"string value"')
```

I tried to specifically cast the path inside my `q` statement, as: `'{path}'::text[]`. Still no error, nor update.

Any idea how I can update a deep JSONB using `psycopg2` and a method like the one above?

**EDIT** - after reading the comments and trying the code of @Abelisto, I've realized what would work (and I feel a bit silly). The following code updates correctly any deep JSONB value:

```py
def update_method(connection, schema, path, value):
   q = f"""UPDATE {schema}."Some_table_name" SET jsonb_col = jsonb_set(jsonb_col, '{path}', '{value}') WHERE id = 1"""
   cur = connection.cursor()
   cur.execute(q)
   connection.commit()
   cur.close()

update_method(conn, 'schema_name', '{path,to,key}', '"string value"')
```

Comment: Do you really missed `jsonb_set` in the python code or it is just the mistyping?

Comment: @Abelisto, just mistyping.

Comment: Works for me (although it is probably subject to SQL injection attacks).  Maybe the path given does not actually exist in the indicated row, so the update doesn't make any visible changes.

Comment: It is steel mystery for me why the global variable does not works but using it as the function parameter it works. Please post the answer about first and second code snippets and why the first one is fail and second one is successful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the solution actually but it is hard to post the python code in the comments.

This question definitely need some debugging. IMO this code snippet should be enough to find the source of the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import psycopg2

schema_name = 'pg_temp'
table_name = 'foo'
init_value = '{"a": "x", "b": {"c": "y"}}'

conn = psycopg2.connect('')

c = conn.cursor();
c.execute(f"""create table {schema_name}.{table_name}(id int, col jsonb)""")
c.execute(f"""insert into {schema_name}.{table_name} values(1, '{init_value}')""")
c.execute(f"""select * from {schema_name}.{table_name} where id = 1""")
print(c.fetchall())

def update_method(schema, path, value):
    qs = f"""select * from {schema}.{table_name} where id = 1"""
    q = f"""UPDATE {schema}.{table_name} SET col = jsonb_set(col, '{path}', '{value}') WHERE id = 1"""
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(qs)
    print(cur.fetchall())
    print(q)
    cur.execute(q)
    cur.execute(qs)
    print(cur.fetchall())
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()

update_method(schema_name, '{b,c}', '"string value"')
```

Output:

```
[(1, {'a': 'x', 'b': {'c': 'y'}})]
[(1, {'a': 'x', 'b': {'c': 'y'}})]
UPDATE pg_temp.foo SET col = jsonb_set(col, '{b,c}', '"string value"') WHERE id = 1
[(1, {'a': 'x', 'b': {'c': 'string value'}})]
```

As you can see the code working for this simple test case.